# WP8 LongListSelector memory leak with TextBlock

Tags: memory-leaks, windows-phone-8, textblock, longlistselector

I have test application:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/y5nxo6esifys4h0/LeakMemLLS.rar

It consists of 2 pages:

1. Main Page.
2. ListItems Page (use LongListSelector).

When I go to ListItems page and back to Main page many time. The memory is increase.

Does anybody know what is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate back from `PhoneApplicationPage`, and then again to it, runtime create a new instance of it. Therefore this memory increase you see. Usually it's okay, since garbage collector will reclaim the unused instances when it will be necessary.

Comment: I used `GC.Colect()`, but memory still increase. When I back to MainPage and go to ListItems page many time. The memory is increase until app crash (out of memory).

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear stack every time when reach `onNavigateTo()` of any page,all pages are maintain in stack and  `GC.Colect()` can not remove your stack.

```
int a = NavigationService.BackStack.Count();
        while (a > standerdCount)
        {
            this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            a = NavigationService.BackStack.Count();
        }
```

**standerdCount** is stack count when app reach to page first time.

Alternatively you can use `NavigationService.GoBack()` when navigate from ListItem Page to MainPage.

Comment: It's good your problem solved by clearing list memory, although  you can also use list.clearAll().